# How to change props object name when it's clicked in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, react-hooks

I'm creating a youtube clone using react js and i used this icon

```
import HomeIconfilled from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined';
```

That looks like this [HomeIconfilled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgLvn.png)

which gets rendered by calling this function

```
        <Sidebariconfunc  Icon={HomeIconfilled} Title="Home"/>
```

That takes 2 parameters and reder the icon

```
function Sidebariconfunc({Icon,Title}) {


return (
    <div className='SidebarRow'>
           <div className='Sidebar_Icon'>
              <Icon/>
           </div>
             <div className='Slidebar_Title'>
                  {Title}
             </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can i chane the props name to HomeIcon when i click on the icon so that it changes to this this icon [HomeIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82SQr.png)
Thamks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function SidebarIcon({ActiveIcon, InactiveIcon, title, isActive}) {
  return (
    <div className='SidebarRow'>
      <div className='Sidebar_Icon'>
        {isActive ? <ActiveIcon/> : <InactiveIcon />
      </div>
      <div className='Slidebar_Title'>{Title}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```js
const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false)

return (
  <a onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)>
    <SidebarIcon
      ActiveIcon={HomeIconfilled}
      InactiveIcon={HomeIcon}
      title='Home'
      isActive={isActive}
    />
  </a>
)
```

Comment: Ty so much ! it worked but i have a big problem :)) because i have 5 icons when i click on one of them the rest changes because they are all bound to the same function ... do you suggest me making a function for every one ?

Comment: don't mind i created 4 more cons{active,setactive} and 4 more functions and it worked :)) if you an easier way please tell me

Comment: Do you mind marking my solution as correct?

Comment: done ! sorry i just saw your comment